# Reverse word letters of a sentence with keeping same word order as entered in emu8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086, microprocessors

I need to write a program in assembly language with `emu8086`, that takes a sentence(include space/blank) and give output with the following conditions:

1. displays the text in the **same word order as entered**, but with the **letters in each word reversed**.
2. Example "`hello world`" input give the output: "`olleh dlrow`"

I tried with the following code:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA

; The string to be printed
STRING DB 'This is a sample string', '$'

.CODE
MAIN PROC FAR
MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX

; call reverse function
CALL REVERSE

; load address of the string
LEA DX,STRING

; output the string
; loaded in dx
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

; interrupt to exit
MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
REVERSE PROC
    ; load the offset of
    ; the string
    MOV SI, OFFSET STRING

    ; count of characters of the;
    ;string
    MOV CX, 0H

    LOOP1:
    ; compare if this is;
    ;the last character
    MOV AX, [SI]
    CMP AL, '$'
    JE LABEL1

    ; else push it in the;
    ;stack
    PUSH [SI]

    ; increment the pointer;
    ;and count
    INC SI
    INC CX

    JMP LOOP1

    LABEL1:
    ; again load the starting;
    ;address of the string
    MOV SI, OFFSET STRING

        LOOP2:
        ;if count not equal to zero
        CMP CX,0
        JE EXIT

        ; pop the top of stack
        POP DX

        ; make dh, 0
        XOR DH, DH

        ; put the character of the;
        ;reversed string
        MOV [SI], DX

        ; increment si and;
        ;decrement count
        INC SI
        DEC CX

        JMP LOOP2

                
    EXIT:
    ; add $ to the end of string
    MOV [SI],'$ '
    RET
        
REVERSE ENDP
END MAIN
```

But this reverses the whole sentence (don't keep the same word order). Like "`hello world`" input gives "`dlrow olleh`" output.

Please suggest how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly used procedure REVERSE to reverse the entire STRING. When you need to reverse each lexical word of the STRING separately, you should similarly split up the task:
parse the input string to words and apply a subprocedure *ReverseWord* to each such word.

Dividing the task to smaller subprocedures makes is better apprehensible and it's easier to debug. You can try to optimize it later, if necessary.

```
REVERSE PROC                ; Reverse words in STRING.
          LEA SI,[STRING]
          CLD               ; LODSB will parse forward.
NextWord: MOV DI,SI         ; Let SI=DI=at the first char of the word.
NextChar: LODSB             ; Load AL from [SI], increment SI.
          CMP AL," "        ; Search for white-space terminator.
          JBE WordEnd
          CMP AL,"$"        ; $ terminates the word, too.
          JE StringEnd
          JMP NextChar      ; Repeat when the word is not terminated yet.
WordEnd:  CALL ReverseWord  ; Reverse the word between DI and SI.
          JMP NextWord
StringEnd:CALL ReverseWord  ; Reverse the last word between DI and SI.
          RET               ; All words are reversed in situ.
        ENDP

ReverseWord PROC            ; Reverse the word between DI and SI-1.
     PUSHAW                 ; Do not clobber any register.
      DEC SI                ; Let SI=behind the last char of the word.
      MOV CX,SI
      SUB CX,DI             ; Let CX=number of chars in the word.
      SHR CX,1              ; Divide CX in half, ignore remainder.
      JZ Done               ; Do nothing when the word is 1 char or less.
Again:DEC SI                ; Let SI=at the last char of the word.
      MOV AL,[SI]           ; Load AL with the last char.
      MOV DL,[DI]           ; Load DL with the first char.
      MOV [SI],DL           ; Swap the first and the last chars.
      MOV [DI],AL
      INC DI
      LOOP Again            ; Repeat with the inner chars.
Done:POPAW                  ; Restore all registers.
     RET                    ; The word between DI..SI was reversed.
    ENDP
```

The inner subprocedure *ReverseWord* is used twice, string terminator **$** remains unclobbered *in situ*.
Notice that the number of character exchanges is half of the word size, and when the word size is odd, the middle character stays in its original position (*in situ*).

Comment: Before my edit, I already suspected that `JBE WordEnd:` (with the colon), was reminiscent of your EuroAssembler. Just verified it is. Still not valid syntax for emu8086 though.

Comment: @SepRoland Indeed it was, thank you. And `JECXZ` was reminiscent of 32bit world; it ought to be `JZ` or `JCXZ` (which **is** supported in `emu8086`, I suppose).