# String Reverse in FASM x86 architecture

Tags: string, assembly, x86, reverse, fasm

I am making a program that reverses a given string from the user.
The problem that has appeared is that the program works well if the string is 5 bytes long but if the string is lower then the result doesn't appear when I execute it. The other problem is that if the string is more than 5 bytes long it reverses only the first five bytes.

Please keep in mind that I am new to assembly and this question may be basic but I would be grateful is someone tells me where the problem is.

Thank you to everyone, have a great day :)

P.S The file "training. inc" is a file that has "print_str, read_line" methods implemented.

```
 entry start

 include "win32a.inc"
 MAX_USER_STR = 5h
 section '.data' data readable writeable
    enter_string db "Enter a string : ", 0
    newline db 13,10,0
    user_str db MAX_USER_STR dup(?), 0
    

 section ".text" code readable executable
 start:
        mov esi, enter_string
        call print_str
        mov edi, user_str
        call read_line
        call str_len
        mov edx, MAX_USER_STR
        mov ebx, 0
        mov ecx, 0
        mov esi, user_str
        call print_str
        mov esi, newline
        call print_str
        mov esi, user_str
        for_loop : 
            push eax
            mov al, byte[esi]
            inc esi
            inc ebx
            call print_eax
            cmp edx, ebx
            jb clear_register
            jmp for_loop    
        
        for_loop2 :
            call print_eax  
            mov byte[esi], al
            inc esi
            inc ecx
            pop eax
            cmp ecx, edx
            ja break_loop
            jmp for_loop2
            
        break_loop:
            ;mov edi, 0
            mov esi, user_str
            call print_str
            push 0
            call [ExitProcess]
        
        clear_register : 
            mov esi, user_str
            jmp for_loop2
        
        str_len : 
            push ecx
            sub ecx, ecx
            mov ecx, -1
            sub al, al
            cld
            repne scasb
            neg ecx
            sub ecx, 1
            mov eax, ecx
            pop ecx
            ret
    
  include 'training.inc'
```

Comment: You declared buffer is 5 bytes so that's your limit.

Comment: Using the machine LIFO stack for reversing strings is prone to errors. Look at the similar question for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68648773/reverse-word-letters-of-a-sentence-with-keeping-same-word-order-as-entered-in-em/68650848#68650848

Comment: @vitsoft the program works very well if I don’t receive a string from the user. Is there a way that I can declare the buffer after I calculate the length of the string

Comment: You already have declared the buffer with `user_str db MAX_USER_STR dup(?), 0`, similary you can declare another buffer with `reversed_str db MAX_USER_STR dup(?), 0` and increase the constant `MAX_USER_STR`. The function `read_line` should tell you how many characters has the user typed, otherwise you need to search for `0x0D` (the terminating Enter) in `user_str`.

Comment: @vitsoft,  the string length is stored in the eax register when I call the "str_len" procedure. Is there a way that I can change the value of the MAX_USER_STR buffer based on the eax register? If yes, can you tell me how to do it? Tried the mov instruction but it did not work. Thanks

Comment: One cannot change the value of asm-time constant but you should make it large enough to hold string of any reasonable size, as Sep suggests. It **is** possible to allocate buffers dynamically at run-time using OS API, but this it not necessary for short strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> MAX_USER_STR = 5h
> ```

The name *MAX_* already says it, but a buffer is to be defined according to the worst case scenario. If you want to be able to deal with strings that could be longer than 5 characters, then raise this value.

```
MAX_USER_STR = 256   ; A decent buffer
```

> ... if the string is lower then the result doesn't appear when I execute it.
> The other problem is that if the string is more than 5 bytes long it reverses only the first five bytes.

That's because your code does not actually *use* the length of the string but rather the size of the smaller buffer. I hope you see that this should never happen, overflowing the buffer. Your code didn't complain too much since this buffer was the last item in the data section.
Your loops could use the true length if you write:

```
call str_len   ; -> EAX
mov  edx, eax
```

---

> ```
>  for_loop : 
>       push eax
>       mov al, byte[esi]
> ```

If it's characters that you want to push, then I would expect the `push eax` to follow the load from the string!
Note that in a string-reversal, you never want to move the string terminator(s) to the front of the string.

This is your basic string reversal via the stack:

```
    mov   ecx, edx       ; EDX has StrLen
    mov   esi, user_str
loop1:
    movzx eax, byte [esi]
    inc   esi
    push  eax
    dec   ecx
    jnz   loop1

    mov   esi, user_str
loop2:
    pop   eax
    mov   [esi], al
    inc   esi
    dec   edx
    jnz   loop2
```

Comment: I wondered if the weird push before load (i.e. pushing last iteration's byte) was intended to avoid moving the terminating zero, if there was one.  (Usually easier to use a read function that tells you how many bytes it read; interfaces that don't provide that are dumb, although do exist.)  But yeah, if you need to strlen then you already have a pointer to the end before you can start swapping anything, so it's more efficient to just walk two pointers in from the ends to meet in the middle, instead of copying to 2x or 4x the stack space and then back.

Comment: @Sep Roland thank you so much for your answer, I appreciate a lot. I fixed the problem (Decremented the value of eax after I called the str_len function).