# Assembly Language 8086 program to print each word in reverse (Letters reversed but words kept in order)

Tags: string, assembly, stack, reverse, emu8086

I'm having issues when I give an input of string with consecutive spaces. If multiple spaces are together the program gives garbage string output. I'm using the EMU8086 emulator. The program works well just as I want it to. But when the user gives an input of multiple spaces together only then the program gives unusual output. Any ideas how to fix this?

I'm using two segments of stacks to store and reverse the characters. I'm using a 100h stack and 50h is where I'm using to store and operate the characters at stack

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data
msg_in  db "Enter a text: $"
msg_out db 0ah, 0dh, "Each word reversed: $"

.code
main proc
  ;init data
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax
  
  ;prompt     
  mov ah, 9
  lea dx, msg_in
  int 21h
  
  ;input 
  xor cx, cx
  INPUT:
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    cmp al, 0dh
    je BR_INPUT 
    xor ah, ah
    push ax
    inc cx
    jmp INPUT
  BR_INPUT: 
  
  ;check for empty input
  cmp cx, 0
  je PRINT
  
  ;process second stack
  mov bx, 50h
  
  REVERSE:
    pop dx
    xchg bx, sp
    push dx
    xchg bx, sp
    loop REVERSE
  
  ;print   
  PRINT:
  mov ah, 9
  lea dx, msg_out
  int 21h
  
  xchg bx, sp
  mov ah, 2
  
  WHILE:
    xor cx, cx  
    
    WORD: 
      cmp sp, 50h
      jge BR_WORD
      pop dx
      cmp dx, 20h
      je BR_WORD
      
      xchg bx, sp
      push dx
      inc cx
      xchg bx, sp 
      
      jmp WORD
      
    BR_WORD:
    
    xchg bx, sp
    
    PRINT_WORD:    
      pop dx
      
      int 21h
      loop PRINT_WORD
    xchg bx, sp
    
    cmp sp, 50h
    jge BR_WHILE
    mov dl, 20h
    int 21h 
    
    jmp WHILE
    
  BR_WHILE:   
        
  ;exit
  mov ah, 4ch
  int 21h
  main endp

end main
```

Comment: This assignment was already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68648773/reverse-word-letters-of-a-sentence-with-keeping-same-word-order-as-entered-in-em/

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @vitsoft I really need mine debugged. I can’t get help from that thread. Isn’t there anyway my code can be fixed?

Comment: I did try debugging. I’m a newbie I dont know how to solve my issue tho

Comment: When the second space is detected, you jump to `BR_WORD` having word lenght  `CX=0`, but you forgot to treat this situation (for instance by `JCXZ WORD` right below the label `BR_WORD:`). so the `loop PRINT_WORD` is performed 65535 times.
If you feel like newbie, don't use split stack and similar overcomplicated  and poorly documented algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Although [the linked Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68648773/reverse-word-letters-of-a-sentence-with-keeping-same-word-order-as-entered-in-em/) does solve the same task, I believe that the fact that you have chosen to use the stack abundantly (and complicated matters) bought you a ticket to a separate answer.

For any sentence where words are separated by solitary spaces all's well:

```
<------------->
My name is Bond
^  ^    ^  ^
================  <= The parts that your code deals with
```

In your program, you have defined the end-of-a-word to be either a single space character or the end of the string. This is fine but if multiple spaces are present, then without provisions, the next word will appear to begin with one or more space characters:

```
<------------------->
My name   is     Bond        
^  ^    ^    ^    
========??===????==== <= The parts that your code tries to deal with
        --   ----     <- Who's gone deal with these parts?
```

The solution is to skip this *leading whitespace* before tackling the next word.
I have added next code to your program and it now works for **any amount of whitespace wherever it's put** (Before the first word, between words, after the last word).

```
; Skip leading whitespace
WHILE:
  cmp   sp, 8000h  ; Might reach the end of the string (trailing whitespace)
  jae   BR_WHILE
  pop   dx
  cmp   dl, " "
  je    WHILE
  push  dx         ; Put back this non-space character
```

Consider next example:

```
<------------------------------->                                 
    My name   is     Bond        
^   ^  ^    ^ ^  ^   ^    ^
    ========  ===    =====        <= The parts that your code dealt with
----        --   ----     ------- <- The parts that the SKIP deals with
```

> ```
> Each word reversed: yM eman si dnoB
> ```

This is the .COM version of your program that I ran. It will work in emu8086:

```
ORG 256

  ;prompt     
  mov ah, 9
  lea dx, msg_in
  int 21h
  
  ;input 
  xor cx, cx
INPUT:
  mov ah, 1
  int 21h
  cmp al, 13
  je BR_INPUT 
  xor ah, ah
  push ax
  inc cx
  jmp INPUT

BR_INPUT: 
  ;check for empty input
  cmp cx, 0
  je PRINT
  
  ;process second stack
  mov bx, 8000h         ;50h
  
REVERSE:
  pop dx
  xchg bx, sp
  push dx
  xchg bx, sp
  loop REVERSE
  
  ;print   
PRINT:
  mov ah, 9
  lea dx, msg_out
  int 21h
  xchg bx, sp
  mov ah, 2
  
WHILE:
  ; Skip leading whitespace
  cmp  sp, 8000h
  jae  BR_WHILE
  pop  dx
  cmp  dl, " "
  je   WHILE
  push dx

  xor cx, cx  
WORD: 
  cmp  sp, 8000h
  jae  BR_WORD
  pop  dx
  cmp  dl, " "
  je   BR_WORD
  xchg bx, sp
  push dx
  inc  cx
  xchg bx, sp
  jmp  WORD

BR_WORD:
  xchg bx, sp

PRINT_WORD:    
  pop dx
  int 21h
  loop PRINT_WORD
  xchg bx, sp
    
  cmp sp, 8000h
  jae BR_WHILE
  mov dl, " "
  int 21h 
  jmp WHILE
    
BR_WHILE:   
  ;exit
  mov ax, 4C00h
  int 21h


msg_in:  db "Enter a text: $"
msg_out: db 10, 13, "Each word reversed: $"
```

Tip: If you plan to use the stack intensively, then better make sure it's big enough. Your original settings of 50h and 100h are rather minimalistic!

Answer (score -2):

```
.MODEL SMALL;Code model set to small
.STACK 100H ;Stack memory 100H size
.CODE       ;Code starts from here

START:      ;Mark start of code segment

INPUT:      ;Mark input of code segment
MOV AH, 1   ;AH=1,Single key input

INT 21H     ;Input in AL
MOV BH, AL  ;BH=AL, 1st input in BH

INT 21H     ;Input in AL
MOV CH, AL  ;CH=AL, 2nd input in CH


OUTPUT:     ;Mark output of code segment
MOV AH, 2   ;AH=2,Single key output

MOV DL, CH  ;DL=CH, Display the 2nd input
INT 21H     ;Print DL
MOV DL, BH  ;DL=BH, Display the 1sd input
INT 21H     ;Print DL


Exit:       ;Mark exit of code segment
MOV AH, 4CH ;4CH = DOS exit fuction. Handover the control to OS and exit program
INT 21H     ;Invoke the instruction for interrupt where there function needs to be executed
```

Comment: This reads 2 bytes and outputs them in reverse order.  They mean reversing English words in a sentence, separated by whitespace or other non-word ASCII characters, not 16-bit `word` integers.

Comment: Consider Writing some text, explaining your answer.